# Set permissions to view but not edit on search

Tags: permissions, people-search

I've built a an Employee Directory following [this guide](https://sympmarc.com/2014/12/26/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365-part-2-set-up-an-employee-directory-page/) but the permissions are giving me grief.  If I add a user to the "Vistors" group, they can see the search box and the refiners but the People Search Core Results webpart just displays an error.  If I add them to the "Members" group everything works fine except they gain editing permissions to everything under xxx.sharepoint.com/search and could wreak havoc if they became disgruntled or pressed the wrong button.  I've also tried the "Restricted Readers" and "Excel Services Viewers" groups just for kicks but to no avail.  I've even tried creating a custom Sharepoint group, but the "read" permission is apparently worthless and there doesn't seem to be a step between no access and full editing for this thing.  Am I missing something or are these just the options I'm stuck with?

Comment: Have you published all of the assets like Display Templates, CSS, and JS files?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yep, looks like that was my problem.  The display templates weren't published.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, here is your answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have published all of your assets like CSS, HTML (display templates), and JS. Usually it is a permissions error.